# Updating count when up/down is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a counter when a user clicks the up or down buttons on my website. At the moment I have this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.up').on('click', function() {
        updateQuantity(1);
    });

    $('.down').on('click', function() {
        updateQuantity(-1);
    });

    function updateQuantity(value) {
        // Get the current quantity
        var count = $('.value').html();

        // Change it according to value passed
        count += value;

        // Write back to HTML
        $('.value').html(count);
    }
});
```

It kinda works, but when I click the up/down buttons it seems to treat `count` as a string, and I end up with an output like this: `0111` or `0-1-1`. How can I force JavaScript to calculate the new count rather than concatinate the string?

Thanks.

Comment: use `parseInt` to convert string to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ihuxiy/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function() { 
    $('.up, .down').on('click', function() {
      var v = parseInt( $('.value').val(), 10 );
      $('.value').val( $(this).hasClass('up') ? v += 1 : v -= 1 );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert to Interger.

`count += value;`

and **convert string into integer** using `parseInt()` because `var count = $('.value').html();` this will return html not a integer value.

so code will look like.

```
var count = parseInt($('.value').html());
count += value; // or count = count + value;
```

#### [`More About parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: yeah, There is one more sulution : var iA = "1"; iCount = iA*1.0 + 1;

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to an integer then.

```
 var count = parseInt($('.value').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` is a string. You should parse it into an integer:

```
var count = parseInt($('.value').text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaSCript has Number function which changes a string to number

```
var count = Number($('.value').html());

count += Number(value);
```

See about [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function here